# Responsive horizontal(desktop)/vertical(mobile) multi level dropdown menu with accordion style sub menus

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, menu

I'm trying to create a horizontal dropdown menu, elements in the dropdown menu may be links or sub menus.  If sub menus, these need to expand/dropdown below the sub menu, effectively extending the original dropdown menu.

I have the functionality kind of working how it's required to do so for both desktop and mobile, this can be viewed here "https://codepen.io/gav75/pen/MWvBawJ"

Issues with what I have at the moment:

- Top menu items don't close when another top menu is opened
- Hover highlight doesn't work on sub menu items

Any help appreciated, thanks.